# Drawing and rotated images using KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

So I been trying to use Konva to draw number of images, text and shapes, everything is fine until I try to add rotation to the mix. I understand that Konva use the origin (top left by default which can be moved by offset) to rotate the image but I need the position to be always top left.

So I have tried to calculate, rotate the re-position the object to mimic what i want, but this always result in the image position to be different to my initial state which is an unwanted behaviour.

so my question is, can Konva rotate images from their centre while maintaining origin position at top left after the rotation?

*Edit with code example:
the green box/text is rotated but the position is all wrong. I'll need the position to be at to left.

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);


const rotatePoint= (x, y , rad)=> {
  const rcos = Math.cos(rad);
  const rsin = Math.sin(rad);
  return {
    x: x * rcos - y * rsin,
    y: y * rcos + x * rsin
  }
}

const rotateAroundCenter = (node, rotation) => {  
  const topLeft = { x: -node.width() / 2, y: -node.height() / 2 };
  const current = rotatePoint(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, Konva.getAngle(node.rotation()));
  const rotated = rotatePoint(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, Konva.getAngle(rotation));
  const dx = rotated.x - current.x,
        dy = rotated.y - current.y;
  
  node.rotation(rotation); 
  
  node.x(node.x() + dx);
  node.y(node.y() + dy);
  
  return node;
}

let x = 100,
    y = 50, 
    width = 50,
    height = 50;
    

const rotation = 90;

const text = { width, height, fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'Calibri', text: 'Simple Text', opacity: 0.5 };
const rect = { width, height, strokeWidth: 2}
let pos = {x, y};
layer.add(new Konva.Circle({ ...pos, radius:5, fill: 'black' })); 
layer.add(new Konva.Text({ ...pos, ...text, fill: 'black' })); 
layer.add(new Konva.Rect({ ...pos, ...rect, stroke: 'purple' })); 
layer.add(new Konva.Text({ ...pos, ...text, fill: 'purple', rotation: rotation })); 
layer.add(new Konva.Rect({ ...pos, ...rect, stroke: 'purple', rotation: rotation }));

pos = {x, y:150};

layer.add(new Konva.Circle({ ...pos, radius:5, fill: 'black' })); 
layer.add(rotateAroundCenter(new Konva.Text({ ...pos, ...text, fill: 'green' }), rotation)); 
layer.add(rotateAroundCenter(new Konva.Rect({ ...pos, ...rect, stroke: 'green' }), rotation)); 



layer.draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="KonvaJS Template">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/4.2.0/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code or minimum representation of your problem

Comment: You can just manually move position of your nodes into the required amount to keep a node on the expected position of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Okay basically had to do what lavrton said, placed the shape in a group (with correct position) then the shape is rotated and offseted inside the group.

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 300,
  height: 700
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const rotatePoint = ({ x, y }, rad) => {
  const rcos = Math.cos(rad);
  const rsin = Math.sin(rad);
  return { x: x * rcos - y * rsin, y: y * rcos + x * rsin };
}

// will work for shapes with top-left origin, like rectangle
const rotateAroundCenter = (node, rotation) => {
  //current rotation origin (0, 0) relative to desired origin - center (node.width()/2, node.height()/2)
  const topLeft = { x: -node.width() / 2, y: -node.height() / 2 };
  const current = rotatePoint(topLeft, Konva.getAngle(node.rotation()));
  const rotated = rotatePoint(topLeft, Konva.getAngle(rotation));
  const dx = rotated.x - current.x,
        dy = rotated.y - current.y;
  
  const r = Math.floor(rotation / 90) % 4;  
  switch(r){
    case 1:
    case 3:
      node.x(node.x() + dx + node.height()/2);
      node.y(node.y() + dy + node.width()/2);
      break;
    case 2:
    default: 
      node.x(node.x() + dx + node.width()/2);
      node.y(node.y() + dy + node.height()/2);
      break;
  }

  node.rotation(rotation);
  
  return node;
}

let x = 200, y = 250, width = 30, height = 75, text = "    ", opacity = 0.4;

drawShapes = (x, y, width, height, rotation) => {  
  layer.add(new Konva.Text({x:0, y, fill: 'black', text: (rotation+"°").padStart(5,"_")}));
  
  layer.add(new Konva.Rect({x, y, width, height, fill: 'black', rotation}));
  layer.add(new Konva.Text({x, y, width, height, fill: 'white', rotation, text}));

  const group = new Konva.Group({ x, y,/* clip:{x:0,y:0,width:200,height:200}*/})
  
  group.add(rotateAroundCenter(new Konva.Rect({x:-width/2,y:-height/2, width, height,fill: 'grey', opacity}), rotation));
  group.add(rotateAroundCenter(new Konva.Text({x:-width/2,y:-height/2, width, height,fill: 'black', text}), rotation));
  layer.add(group, new Konva.Circle({x, y, radius: 2, fill: 'black'}));
}
drawShapes(x, 50, width, height,   0);
drawShapes(x, 200, width, height,  90);
drawShapes(x, 350, width, height, 180);
drawShapes(x, 500, width, height, 270);


layer.draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="KonvaJS Template">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/4.2.0/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="height:700px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```